# How to do the base turn course reversal?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules

Can anyone tell me how to do the base turn course reversal? Please. I'm afraid it might be asked of me in my Checkride and my instructors haven't taught me that. Please.

Comment: Why aren't you asking your instructors about it?

Comment: Fixed it for ya.

Comment: Not a bad idea to broaden you understanding on a forum like this because opinions and techniques vary, but you really need to ask the person you hired to prepare you for the checkride.

Answer (score 1):

If your worried something will be on the checkride (which is practical) you need to seek out more practical instruction on the maneuver.

[Procedurally this site offers a good explanation](http://code7700.com/course_reversals.htm#baseturn):

> Base turn consists of:
>
> 1. a specified outbound track and timing or DME distance from a facility; followed by
> 2. a turn to intercept the inbound track
>
> The outbound track and/or the timing may be different for the various
>   categories of aircraft. Where this is done, separate procedures are
>   published.